# Deployment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Docker fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, playframework, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm developing a web application with Play framework and I'm running it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using a single docker container and a load balancer. Normally, everything is running fine, but when I rebuild the whole environment I get the following error:

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 6 Output: (TRUNCATED)... in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11 nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "docker" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:24 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed.

When I log into the EC2 I can see that no docker image is running and therefore the Nginx server cannot start. I cannot see any other error in the logs (or maybe I don't know where to look). The strange thing is that the same version worked fine before rebuilding the environment.

I'm using the following Dockerfile for the deployment:

```
FROM java
COPY <app_folder> /opt/<app_name>
WORKDIR /opt/<app_name>
CMD [ "/opt/<app_name>/bin/<app_name>", "-mem", "512", "-J-server" ]
EXPOSE 9000
```

Any ideas what the problem could be or where to check for more details?

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem. `elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf` is referring to `proxy_pass http://docker` but the definition of that is missing. You need to add something like

```
    # List of application servers
    upstream docker {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;  # your app
    }
```

(Make sure it's outside of the `server` directive.)

Comment: This is not true (perhaps this file was added in the 4 years since this answer). But you can find the upstream definition at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf`

Answer (score -1):

I have just been working through the same challenge (deploying an updated Docker image to Elastic Beanstalk). And it depends on what you want to do exactly, but what I found out is that (once you have the eb cli setup) you can just use the `eb deploy` command to push out your code changes without worrying about the image at all.

Granted you'd still want to push your image up to your repo for sharing purposes (with other developers), OR if you actually need to change the environment configuration for some reason... but if you're just looking to push code look into `eb deploy`

As far as the specifics of your error unfortunately I can't be of much help there. Good luck!